# Correção de linha de comando R em ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Utilizei o seguinte código para gerar o gráfico em anexo

```
ggplot(dados,aes(x = Espécies, y = DNASat, size = Reads, fill=Espécies)) + 
  scale_y_discrete(limits = positions) + 
  geom_point(shape = 21) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Pastel1") + 
  scale_size_area(max_size=13)
```

Nesse código utilizei a função `scale_y_discrete(limits = positions)` para ordenar o dados no eixo Y como estão no gráfico, porém, como dá para perceber, perdi metade do espaço útil desse gráfico ao fazer isso e não sei o motivo. Alguém sabe como arrumar isso?

Em anexo o `dput(dados)`

```
dados <-
structure(list(DNASat = c("CpaSat1A", "CpurSat2A", "CpurSat3Y", 
"CpurSat4A", "CpurSat5Y", "CpurSat6Z", "CpurSat7Y", "CpurSat8B", 
"CpurSat9Z", "CpurSat10Y", "CameSat1A", "CameSat2B", "CameSat3Y", 
"CameSat4Y", "CpaSat1A", "CpurSat2A", "CpurSat3Y", "CpurSat4A", 
"CpurSat5Y", "CpurSat6Z", "CpurSat7Y", "CpurSat8B", "CpurSat9Z", 
"CpurSat10Y", "CameSat1A", "CameSat2B", "CameSat3Y", "CameSat4Y"
), Espécies = c("Cenchrus purpureus", "Cenchrus purpureus", "Cenchrus purpureus", 
"Cenchrus purpureus", "Cenchrus purpureus", "Cenchrus purpureus", 
"Cenchrus purpureus", "Cenchrus purpureus", "Cenchrus purpureus", 
"Cenchrus purpureus", "Cenchrus purpureus", "Cenchrus purpureus", 
"Cenchrus purpureus", "Cenchrus purpureus", "Cenchrus americanus", 
"Cenchrus americanus", "Cenchrus americanus", "Cenchrus americanus", 
"Cenchrus americanus", "Cenchrus americanus", "Cenchrus americanus", 
"Cenchrus americanus", "Cenchrus americanus", "Cenchrus americanus", 
"Cenchrus americanus", "Cenchrus americanus", "Cenchrus americanus", 
"Cenchrus americanus"), Reads = c(35629, 33216, 31812, 30664, 
7534, 7128, 6395, 1887, 1069, 272, 31857, 1865, 1435, 18, 28201, 
25900, 25967, 25987, 0, 11419, 0, 11879, 0, 0, 26206, 11887, 
336, 220)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -28L))
```

e `dput(positions)`

```
positions <-
c("CameSat4Y", "CameSat3Y", "CameSat2B", "CameSat1A", "CpurSat10Y", 
"CpurSat9Z", "CpurSat8B", "CpurSat7Y", "CpurSat6Z", "CpurSat5Y", 
"CpurSat4A", "CpurSat3Y", "CpurSat2A", "CpaSat1A", "CameSat4Y", 
"CameSat3Y", "CameSat2B", "CameSat1A", "CpurSat10Y", "CpurSat9Z", 
"CpurSat8B", "CpurSat7Y", "CpurSat6Z", "CpurSat5Y", "CpurSat4A", 
"CpurSat3Y", "CpurSat2A", "CpaSat1A")
```

[image: gráfico]

Comment: Dá erro: `Error in ggproto(NULL, super, call = match.call(), aesthetics = aesthetics,  : object 'positions' not found`.

Comment: Foi mal, eu pedi o ```dput``` só de dados. Coloquei a correção.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema está na repetição de valores no vetor `positions`. Só há 14 valores todos eles repetidos. Então o argumento `limits` reserva espaço para 14*2 posições no eixo dos `y`.

Creio que a maneira mais natural é transformar o vetor `DNASat` em fator com os níveis definidos pela ordem de valores em `positions`. Mas para isso vou ficar só com os *repetidos*, porque é a segunda metade de `positions` que define a ordem pretendida.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dados %>%
  mutate(DNASat = factor(DNASat, levels = positions[duplicated(positions)]))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Espécies, y = DNASat, size = Reads, fill = Espécies)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Pastel1") +
  scale_size_area(max_size=13)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Entendi, mas perceba que utilizando esse comando a ordem do eixo Y é alterada em relação ao gráfico que criei.

Comment: @AlexSilvestrini Finalmente! Veja agora.

Comment: Deu certo cara. Muito obrigado.